# Compare one textview before and after

Tags: java, android

I want to compare the text of a single textview before and after changes
eg. The textview is 9 if the value of 9 is show again(is receiving the data from JSON) in that TextView I want to bring an alert saying that is equal to the previous textview value.

I have this code(Note that I know this is wrong is just for context purpose):

```
if(brandnumber.getText.toString.equals(brandnumber.getText.toString){
//Alert saying its the same value after and before
}
```

Comment: You may have to bring up more context.

Answer (score 2):

1. Store the *"before"* value in a correct datatype (`String`, `int`,..)
2. Compare the *"new"* value with the stored value if they match (like you did in your example)

   ```
   // The initial value, store it in String
   String beforeText = brandnumber.getText().toString();

   // After change occurs (e.g.new data from JSON) in TextView store the new value in String
   String currentText = brandnumber.getText().toString();
   // Now you can create a method for comparing the values which will return the boolean True of False depending if they match
   if(compareTextValues(beforeText,currentText) {
       // Do what you want here if they match
   }

   // Method to compare two string, it returns True if they match
   private boolean compareTextValues(String beforeText, String currentText)
   {
    return beforeText.equals(currentText);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the previous value
String mText = brandnumber.getText().toString();

//set the new value
brandnumber.setText("9");

// compare two values
if(text.equals(brandnumber.getText().toString()){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this questions using the aftertextchanged method and beforetextchanged method that all the TextViews have :) Thanks to all